# auto-increment php variable within POST

Tags: php

I'm struggling to understand exactly what's going wrong with this code.  I'd love it if someone could help explain to me what I am doing wrong.  At the bottom, there is a table with a "next" button.  Each time someone clicks on this button, I want to increase TWO values.  The first one, $nextLimit, is fine - it increases by 10 each time I press "Next," but the second one, $pageNumber, is not working.  I want it to increase by 1 each time I hit "Next," but it just stays at 0 and I can't figure out why.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
    $postedLimit = (isset($_POST['next']) ? (int) $_POST['next'] : 0);
    $nextLimit = $postedLimit + 10;

// Begin code that isn't working....
    session_start();
      if (isset($_SESSION['page'])) { /* If there is already a value set */
      $_SESSION['page']++; /* Increment by 1 */
      }
      else { /* If there is no value set, ie the user is clicking the button for the first time */
        $_SESSION['page'] = 1; /* Set to 1 */
      }
    $_SESSION['page'] =  $pageNumber;
// End code that isn't working....
    echo $pageNumber ; 
    echo "<br>" ; 
    echo $nextLimit ;


    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM report WHERE PMName = '$PMSelection' AND REGNSB <> 0.000 ORDER BY RegNSB DESC Limit $nextLimit,$LimitItems");
}
?>
```

Then, the HTML that links back to this  $_POST['next']

```
<table id="box-table-a" stlye="widgth:20%">
<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="container">
<div class="right">Page <?= $pageNumber ?> of <?= $totalPages ?> 
<input type="submit" name="previous" value="prev">  
<input type="submit" name="next" value="next" onclick="this.value=<?php echo $nextLimit; ?>">

</div>
</form>
</div>
</table>
```

I assume that when I press "next," the code goes over to the

```
if (isset($_POST['next']))
```

line, then executes the code there.  The session should initialize, and $pageNumber should increment by 1 each time, but it's not.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's arriving at the server? e.g. if the JS isn't working, then you're sending `next=next`, and `(int)next` -> `0`.

Comment: Yup - I'm getting **var_dump($pageNumber)** as **NULL** regardless of what I do.  my **var_dump($_POST)** is **array(1) { ["next"]=> string(4) "next" }**.  Not sure what that means though.......

Comment: Why are you incrementing the session variable, and then immediately overwriting it with `$pageNumber`? Where do you set `$pageNumber`

Comment: I was trying to take whatever value was in $_SESSION['page'] and assign it to $pageNumber, so I could use $pageNumber later on in the code instead of $_SESSION['page'].  Basically - I was attempting to "rename" that variable.

Comment: If I take that out - my var_dump of $_SESSION['page'] is int(1) (instead of NULL).  But it stays at that value regardless of how many times I press "next".

Comment: so yeah... the dump shows that the browser is sending the value `next` for your submit button, e.g. the javascript isn't firing, and the hard-coded `value="next"` is what's going out on the wire.

Comment: Thank you for showing me var_dump - I hadn't used this before and it's really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['page'])) { /* If there is already a value set */
    $_SESSION['page']++; /* Increment by 1 */
}
else { /* If there is no value set, ie the user is clicking the button for the first time */
    $_SESSION['page'] = 1; /* Set to 1 */
}
$_SESSION['page'] =  $pageNumber;
```

with

```
$_SESSION['page'] = (int) $nextLimit / 10;
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that....... it makes perfect sense and it works :)  thank you :)